# Creating a calendar app in ASP.NET, dealing with timezones

Tags: asp.net, datetime, calendar, timezone

I am writing a calendar website using ASP.NET 3.5 and SQL Server 2008, and want to handle timezones in the best possible way.  I've read these sources:

[Daylight saving time and time zone best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-timezone-best-practices)

http://noda-time.blogspot.com/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973825.aspx.

I've got all the general info down, but having a tough time converting this to actual code.  Not looking for someone to write the code for me, but would help if I knew what others are doing for this very specific case (Calendar app, Date/Time for events, since "5pm eastern" should always be "5pm eastern" even if rules change).

Are you using .NET DateTimeOffset and TimeZoneInfo classes?  I don't see that they support something like "convert this UTC time to EST using the rules that were present Jan 2 2011", which I think is the level of control you need to create a calendar app that "correctly" handles timezones.  I also don't think everyone doing this is using Noda Time because I hardly find any examples or discussion about that library.  Probably the Java version is used a lot, but a lot of apps are written in .NET, so what are they doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really thinking this is the correct answer, but thought it was better to post as an answer -- in the off chance this is correct, and also just because it's easier to read/follow this way.

**Please let me know if I'm headed the correct direction:**

1. Use DateTimeOffset and TimeZoneInfo classes
2. In the database save DateTimeOffset value and offset.  Also save TimeZoneInfo.id (tz id).
3. Before using the value from the database, always compare the saved offset with the current TimeZoneInfo offset, and adjust the DateTimeOffset value by the difference.  This is what fixes "the govt changed the rules" issue and keeps a "4pm eastern" time as "4pm eastern" (even if the offset from UTC has changed due to new rules).
4. To make queries that look for specific date/times or ranges work, anytime the rules change (by govt), go through and "fix" every record in your database.  The fix is same steps used for #3 above, but save the new values after fixing.

Is this what others are doing?  Not real crazy about #4, since I'll need to do that around the same time as Windows updates are applied with new rules... any time between Windows update and my database update being complete, it could produce invalid query results.  I guess that's what "scheduled maintenance" is for, but we don't currently have such a strict policy for that.